# When app crashes for live capture detect text in get an image from the AVCaptureDataSampleBufferDelegate call back did output

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturedevice, avcapture

When an app crashes for live capture detect text in getting an image from the `AVCaptureDataSampleBufferDelegate` call back did output.
Get image call back from the send Google vision API I have used that code 
Did anyone work?
My code

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseMLVision
import FirebaseMLModelInterpreter
import AVKit

protocol ImageDelegate: class {
  func getImage(imageOutFrame: String)
}
var photoOutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput!
var videoDataOutputQueue: DispatchQueue!
var previewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice!
var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var context = CIContext()
weak var delegate: ImageDelegate?
var vision = Vision.vision()
var textRecognizer = vision.onDeviceTextRecognizer()

extension UIViewController: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {      
  // To set the camera and its position to capture
  func setUpAVCapture(capturePreview: UIView) {
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.vga640x480
    guard let device = AVCaptureDevice
      .default(AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera,
               for: .video,
               position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.back) else {
                return
    }
    captureDevice = device
    captureDevice.isFocusModeSupported(.continuousAutoFocus)
    try! captureDevice.lockForConfiguration()
    captureDevice.focusMode = .continuousAutoFocus
    captureDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
    beginSession(capturePreview: capturePreview)
  }
// Function to setup the beginning of the capture session
  func beginSession(capturePreview : UIView){

    var deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!

    do {
      deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
      guard deviceInput != nil else {
        print("error: cant get deviceInput")
        return
      }
      if captureSession.canAddInput(deviceInput){
        captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)
      }         
      photoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
      photoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames=true
      videoDataOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "VideoDataOutputQueue")
      photoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: videoDataOutputQueue)            
      if captureSession.canAddOutput(photoOutput){
        captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput)
      }          
      photoOutput.connection(with: .video)?.isEnabled = true          
      previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
      previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill          
      let rootLayer :CALayer = capturePreview.layer
      rootLayer.masksToBounds=true          
      rootLayer.addSublayer(previewLayer)          
       captureDevice.configureDesiredFrameRate(0)          
      captureSession.startRunning()
    } catch let error as NSError {
      deviceInput = nil
       exit(0)
      print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }        
  }     
  public func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait            
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
      guard let imag = self.imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer : sampleBuffer) else { return }
    let image = VisionImage(image: imag)
    textRecognizer.process(image) { result, error in
      guard error == nil, let result = result else {
        return
      }
      let resultText = result.text
      let matched = self.matches(for: RegEx.wholeRegex , in: resultText)          
      let m = matched.joined(separator: "")
      print(m)          
      delegate?.getImage(imageOutFrame: m)
      }
  }
  }      
  func imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer : CMSampleBuffer) -> UIImage? {
    guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return nil }
    let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: imageBuffer)
    guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) else { return nil }        
    let img = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    let n = img.fixedOrientation()
    return n
  }
  func stopCamera(){
    captureSession.stopRunning()
    captureDevice = nil
  }      
}    
extension AVCaptureDevice {      
  /// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612191/set-a-custom-avframeraterange-for-an-avcapturesession#27566730
  func configureDesiredFrameRate(_ desiredFrameRate: Int) {        
    var isFPSSupported = false        
    do {          
      if let videoSupportedFrameRateRanges = activeFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges as? [AVFrameRateRange] {
        for range in videoSupportedFrameRateRanges {
          if (range.maxFrameRate >= Double(desiredFrameRate) && range.minFrameRate <= Double(desiredFrameRate)) {
            isFPSSupported = true
            break
          }
        }
      }          
      if isFPSSupported {
        try lockForConfiguration()
        activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: Int32(desiredFrameRate))
        activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: Int32(desiredFrameRate))
        unlockForConfiguration()
      }          
    } catch {
      print("lockForConfiguration error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
  }
}
```

get let r`esultText = result.text` get only doller value 
for example live capture

> xcsrf$16.54245 ssxvcxv

I got an Output for like

$16.54245

- > My problem is app getting slow recognition of text.
- 1) I have set frames rate but not working
- 2) I have used Dispatch but not working.
- > get frames -> converted to image  converted to image -> send google
- > vision API detecting text - > converted to get the only exact output

**> Please share your code to be appreciated Thanks.**

Comment: Hey Arun, it's really hard to understand what your actual problem is. Can you please try and re-frame your question to make it a little more clear what isn't working, and how you expect it to work?

Answer (score 0):

My app also crashes when I initialise a `VisionImage` object with `UIImage` in `captureOutput` method. The reason I don't initialise `VisionImage` with `CMSampleBuffer` is that I needed to crop specific part of my camera preview layer. It was difficult for me to crop `CMSampleBuffer`.


**Reason**
For my case, the crash happens when a new video frame becomes keep available while the text recogniser is still running because `captureOutput` was repeatedly called when camera is on.


**Solution**
I put a flag variable to prevent calling the text recogniser while it is processing image. Check the following code for detail.

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

    guard let image = self.imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer : sampleBuffer) else { return }
    let image = VisionImage(image: image)

    guard isRunningTextRecognizer == false else {
            return
    }

    isRunningTextRecognizer = true
    let textRecognizer = vision.onDeviceTextRecognizer()
    textRecognizer.process(image) { (text, error) in
        //...
        self.isRunningTextRecognizer = false
        //..
    }
}
```

I hope it help!.